# Register plugin for only one directory in python project

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, hook

I have this python project with three directories, **my_dir1**, **my_dir2**, and **my_dir3**. Within **my_dir1** I have defined a plugin that I would like to use for **my_dir2** but *not* **my_dir3**. The problem is that even though I have configured the `conftest.py` for **my_dir2** to register the plugin, it seems to be applied to **my_dir3** as well. Since I do not want the plugin to apply to **my_dir3**, how do I prevent this from happening?

P.S. I should add that methods in **my_dir3** are invoking methods in **my_dir2**

Comment: There is not enough information to make sense of your question. E.g., what is a plugin, what does it mean to register it, what is the role of `conftest.py`, ...?

Comment: I essentially want to disable the plugin for a particular directory. By plugin, I mean a set of hooks that are called on methods.